# Adding a Search Bar to a Table View with Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data

I have an app that saves data to a Core Data sql then view it in a table view.

The data model:

```
Entity: Fruits

Attributes:  name, picture
```

So in the table view, **cell.textLabel.text = Fruits.name**

Each cell has a segue with a view that shows **Fruits.picture**.

I want to add a search bar to search in Fruits names.

I followed this tutorial: http://www.appcoda.com/search-bar-tutorial-ios7/

But the problem I had is in **filterContentForSearchText**

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", searchText];
    searchResults = [recipes filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}
```

I'm using core data not an array for storing data. And I don't know how to filter it so I can display searchResults in table cells and use it in prepareForSegue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using core data and not an array of Fruits you should filter your data this way:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"Fruits" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", searchText];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error;

    NSArray* searchResults = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
}
```

To show the picture in a second viewController you should put something like this in you **prepareForSegue** method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    Fruit *selectedItem;
    if (self.searchDisplayController.active) {
        selectedItem = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        selectedItem = [fruitsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    DestinationViewController *destination = segue.destinationViewController;
    destination.fruit = selectedItem;
}
```

Where fruitsList is an array with all the fruit objects (The one used to show the fruits without any filter), and `DestinationViewController` is the the controller that will show the picture.

Comment: Thanks, but how would I use it in **prepareForSegue**? using NSArray will only show the cells textLabels but how to access the object itself so when I click the searched cell it goes to its picture view?

Comment: I added what would `prepareForSegue` look like in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

First, why is your entity name in the plural? That is confusing. You should rename your entity `Fruit`.

Second, how come your variable names start with capital letters? This is again confusing because they can be mistaken for class names. You should rename your variables `fruit`, such as in `fruit.name`.

Third, you should use a `NSFetchedResultsController` to populate your table view. You could have a separate one just for the search or filter in memory. Both are preferable to doing a manual fetch in each call to `filterContentForSearchText`. Your filter code looks fine (it is the in-memory version). However, I do not see where you reload the data of your search results table view.

Fourth, the search is completely unrelated to the segue problem. Each cell should be associated with a particular `Fruit` instance. (Either custom cells with a `@property` of type `Fruit`, or use the fetched results controller `objectAtIndexPath`.) In `prepareForSegue` you just assign that fruit to the detail view controller (which should have an appropriate `@property` set up).